# Assign value if empty if not increment the value (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

Is it possible in matlab to check if a value is empty and if it is empty assign a value, else (if it is not empty) increment the value during an assignment ?

For example:

In this code I increment `majorityList{l}`, though at the start this cell is empty (not 0), therefore i can't increment it. This means I need to check this first before I can increment it. Can this be done during the assignment itself ?

```
 majorityList{l,2} = 'test'; 
 majorityList{l}=  majorityList{l}+1;
```

A solution I wrote is:

```
if length(majorityList{l})==0 
     majorityList{l} = 0;
     majorityList{l} = majorityList{l} +1;
else
    majorityList{l} = majorityList{l} +1; 
 end
```

though this looks rather ugly for something so easy...

Comment: It is uselss to write `majorityList{l} = majorityList{l} +1;` on both side of the `else`. Just write it once after the `end`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html;jsessionid=8256e47aa83f3da44e2e258b2b29) for that

```
if ~isempty(var)
   var=var+1;
end
```

If on the other hand you do not know, if the variable exists at all, use [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/exist.html).

Answer (score 4):

*If you are incrementing single-value variables*, and not matrices elementwise, you can do the one-liner, no-checker

```
var = sum(var) + 1;
```

Sum will give 0 for empty matrices and the actual value of `var` otherwise (as single-element sum). From the non-empty outputs of operators on [empty matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html#f1-86384), sum will give a correct output for both empty and non-empty values.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're going to increment it in a loop, the easiest solution is just to initialize `majorityList` to zero outside the loop:

```
majorityList{1} = 0;
while loop==running
    majorityList{1} = majorityList{1}+1;
end
```